# SQL: how to aggregate value with conditions (CASE WHEN???)

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

My data has 3 variables, User ID, Transaction Amount, and Transaction Date,
I want to aggregate 2 day transaction amount for each user ID, but with conditions.

The condition is, for example, I want to aggregate 8/31 and 8/30 transaction amount for an ID 12345, if the transaction amount is 0 on 8/31 for this ID, which means this ID does not have any transactions on 8/31, then just ignore this user ID, I'm not going to aggregate amount for this user ID.

If another ID 23456 has transactions on 8/31 and does not have transaction on 8/30, then I will aggregate the transactions on 8/31 for this ID.

If one ID 34567 has transactions on both 8/30 and 8/31, then I will have aggregate the transactions for both 8/30 and 8/31.

How can I do this? I've been struggling for the whole afternoon. Thanks in advance for any suggestions and idea!

Comment: I removed the incompatible databasse tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question should be

```
 select  user_id, sum(a.transaction_amount + b.transaction_amount).
 from my_table as a
 inner join  my_table as b on date_add(b.transaction_date, interval 1 day) =  a.transaction_date
 where date(a.transaction_date) =  STR_TO_DATE('31,8,2016','%d,%m,%Y')
 and a.transaction_amount > 0
 group by user_id
```

Comment: Thank you! I see how it works now, appreciate your answer!

Comment: @user3716379   . if you appreciate  my (and the others) answer  . you can rate as useful  ..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User_ID, SUM(Transaction_Amount)
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE(Transaction_Date) = '2016-08-30'
  OR (DATE(Transaction_Date) = '2016-08-31' AND Transaction_Amount > 0)
GROUP BY User_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select userid,
       sum(case when date = '2016-08-30' then amount else 0 end) as amt_20160830,
       sum(case when date = '2016-08-31' then amount else 0 end) as amt_20160831
from t
group by userid
having sum(case when date = '2016-08-31' then amount else 0 end) > 0;
```

Exactly what the code looks like might vary by databases, but this is fairly standard SQL.

Comment: Thank you! I see how it works now, appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to return only users which had a transaction on Aug. 31.:

```
select userid,
       sum(trans_amount)
from t
where trans_date between date '2016-08-30' and date '2016-08-31'
group by userid
having max(trans_date) = date '2016-08-31'
```

Comment: Thank you! I see how it works now, appreciate your answer!